# CopyFromRecordset paste to last row

Tags: sql, vba

Is it possible to use a CopyFromRecordset in vba to paste an sql query to the last row in excel?

For example, using the below would paste to C12....how would I do to the last row of C?

```
Set recset = New ADODB.Recordset
    recset.Open SQLQry, Conn
    Range("C12").CopyFromRecordset recset
    recset.Close
```

I've tried `C12:C & lastrow` where lastrow is `lastrow = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` but I get a "method range of object global failed" error....

Any help would be amazing!

Comment: Just try `Range("C" & lastrow)`

Comment: Or even `Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)`

Comment: `Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)` this was the one that worked....`Range("C" & lastrow)` still came up with the same error - thank you both for the help!